# Why do I call this method and then current VC automatically back to the rootVC

Tags: ios, objective-c

I call this method

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion: nil];
```

and then current VC automatically back to the rootVC.

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"取消" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    // 直接取消
}];
UIAlertAction *photo = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"拍照" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    // 拍照
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
UIAlertAction *album = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"从相册中选取" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    // 从相册中选取
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
[actionSheet addAction:photo];
[actionSheet addAction:album];
[actionSheet addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
    self.user_icon.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSArray *arr = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
    // Log "<PersonViewController: 0x7f9bf485be00>"
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion: ^{
        NSArray *arr = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
        NSLog(@"%@",arr);
        // Log (null)
    }];
}`

I do not know where I set up wrong, but the same code in another project not wrong , please help me solve this problem , thank you！

> Latest update：

Question wrong place：

I placed UITabBarController initialization inside viewWillAppear

> before code:

`- (id)initWithLoginType:(LoginType)loginType{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.loginType = loginType;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self loadTabBarControllers];
}
- (void)loadTabBarControllers{
   xxxxxxxx UITabBarController initialization
}`

> After Code:

`- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    LoginType loginType = appDelegate.loginType;
    xxxxxxxx UITabBarController initialization
}`

> Although the problem has been solved , but I'm still not sure why UITabBarController initialization on viewWillAppear this (presentViewController and then dismissViewController. the currentVC is released, and automatically back to rootVC) happen ?

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion: nil] will definitely bring  you back to the VC where you presented your current view modally. What are you expecting to happen then?

Comment: TRY THIS : dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    });

Comment: @JLT I just need to return to the currentVC

Comment: @MikeAlter I just tried, but no effect

Comment: which one is your current VC and Root VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your imagePicker. Image picker is working as it have to.
I might have figured out the cause.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self loadTabBarControllers];
}
```

This line will load tabor when ever the view will appear setting all navigation to its root view controller.

So, in your case when ever the imagePicker is dismissed.

```
viewWillAppear()
```

will executed and sets the tabbar again.

Remove `[self loadTabBarControllers];` from viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance！

Answer (score 2):

`dismissViewControllerAnimated` pop you back to previous view controller which was available in your navigation stack. so make sure that you are not releasing your previous viewcontrollers from navigation hierarchy. Make sure that your current viewcontroller was there in navigation stack.

You can check your navigation stack by,

```
NSArray *arr = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

Put this two line in `actionWithTitle` method as last line. After presenting `imagePicker`.

then you will get your view hierarchy.

I assume that you have used navigation controller.

second thing you should dismiss your `imagePickerController`.

Comment: View controller is really being released out！！！But I still do not know why it had been released ?

Comment: That you should check. Why is it so!!! It's depends how you add viewcontroller to navigation stack. Add your code that how you are doing this. You should have strong reference to previous viewcontrollers. Are you presenting viewcontroller or pushing it on navigation stack?

Comment: How you add `PersonViewController` ? Is it in storyboard ? have you given segue for it ? aur are you creating it programatically ? are presenting it or pushing it?

Comment: I have re-edited my question. PersonViewController is one navigantionVC of the UITabBarController.viewControllers

Comment: It is a xib. I just would like to take a photo of a system inside a photo , and then assigned. Just present a imagePicker

Answer (score 1):

You present the `UIImagePickerController` on self and then you try to dismiss `self` in your `imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method.

`self` is not what you want to be dismissing.

Try dismissing the `UIImagePickerController` instead:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
    self.user_icon.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    // CHANGE BELOW FROM SELF TO PICKER
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion: nil];
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method, but to no avail. Now find where the problem is , it is that the navigationVC was released out ! But I still do not know why it had been released?

Comment: are you sure? is that method being called? It does seem like you set the delegate to self, so are you making sure you're conforming to the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate? I.e. @interface MyViewController () <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> ?

Comment: I just tried this method, but to no avail. Before the imagePicker dismiss, the navigationVC  has not been released out. But when dismiss the animation is finished , navigationVC was released out. I do not understand that I was not doing something wrong operation

Comment: can u try doing this? Add breakpoint just before presenting UIActionController and in the (lldb) type `po [[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]`. Continue this process by adding a breakpoint inside the handler for the UIAlert just before you present the image picker, and then again in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` just before you dismiss, and probably just after you dismiss. this should print out the entire controller hierarchy to make it a bit easier to see whats going on

Comment: Thank you in advance to help me so much！ I have put the print in my question.

Comment: get rid of the first two ones and repeat the process but in the completion of the dismissViewController

also, just to clarify this is being done inside MainViewController or PersonViewController? what is self in all this

Comment: before dismiss :<PersonViewController 0x7f873af4dc90>                         after dismiss:  po self
<PersonViewController: 0x7f873ace6e00>   I found that the memory address has changed, but I still can not determine where to perform the method of release